# How to pass integer as paramater in Jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have this code. Now I want to pass the value of the selected item in dropdown then save it in my database.

```
<select name="Organization" class="txtbox">
                            <%
                                Iterator it = EMS_Items.iterator();
                                while (it.hasNext())
                                {
                                    EMSItems newsItem3 = (EMSItems) it.next();
                            %>
                            <option value="${newsItem3.getOrgId()}"><%=newsItem3.getOrgName()%></option>
                            <%
                                }
                            %>

                    </select>
```

what i did was

```
long statOrgId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("Organization"));
    emsItem.setStatOrgId(statOrgId);
```

but it gives me an error of

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

can somebody help me?thanks

Answer (score 1):

The parameter Organization is an empty String ""

```
req.getParameter("Organization")
```

So what you need to do is make sure the parameter "Organization" is set.

Then in your code add a condition check:

```
if ( req.getParameter("Organization") != null && !"".equals(req.getParameter("Organization")) {
    long statOrgId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("Organization"));
    emsItem.setStatOrgId(statOrgId);
}
```

Comment: Same thing happened...it stores a value of "0" in the database...The id of the organization was not able to pass

Comment: OK, then it is another problem. You need to find out why the value was not able to pass in

Comment: I already resolve the problem I change the value parameter to value=<%=newsItem3.getOrgId()%>